# Why org.json.JSONObject excludes POJO fields start with x while converting to JSON object?

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

Diferent results occur when mapping an object containing a field starting with "x" to [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectMapper`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

**`JSONObject`**

```json
{"one":"One"}
```

**`ObjectMapper`**

```json
{"one":"One","xOne":"xOne"}
```

Why does the `JSONObject` not include the "xOne" field?

```java
public class Test {
    
    private String one;
    private String xOne;

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String getxOne() {
        return xOne;
    }

    public void setxOne(String xOne) {
        this.xOne = xOne;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test [one=" + one + ", xOne=" + xOne + "]";
    }

}

public class PojoToJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setOne("One");
        test.setxOne("xOne");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(test);
        System.out.println("JSONObject o/p: " + json);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String mapperString = mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
        System.out.println("ObjectMapper o/p: " + mapperString);
    }
}
```

Here is my output difference using `JSONObject` and `ObjectMapper`:

[image: IDE screenshot of program output]

Comment: `getxOne()` may not be seen as a getter. Try renaming to `getXOne()` instead.

Comment: Interesting...these are the auto generated setters and getters and it's hard to do it manually where you have more than 50 variables.

Comment: @gwell it worked...you may want to conver your comment into answer

Comment: @gwell so the conclusion here is ObjectMapper is checking case insensitive getter name and JSONObject has strict getter check?

Comment: FWIW, Jackson has its own JSONObject classes, and shouldn't be using `org.json` imports with it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jackson reference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html):

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, the default Java property
> naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is, and removes
> set/get/is prefix from methods (as well as lower-cases initial
> sequence of capitalized characters).

As I understand it, this means that Jackson will understand that `getxOne()` actually correspond to `xOne` property.

`org.json.JSONObject` may have a different naming strategy (which I was not able to find anywhere) and hence the reason for `getxOne()` to work with Jackson's `ObjectMapper` but not with `org.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: The other possibility, and I would need to play around with this to determine if it's the case, is that Jackson doesn't understand the `getxOne` and is instead using the field names to determine the mapping.  You very well might be right, though.

Comment: That might also be the case. Jackson is missing some examples so that we know for sure what would be the behaviour when the first letter after `get` is lowercase.

Comment: It'd be easy enough to test, but I'm not somewhere I can poke around with it at the moment.